# Google reCaptcha v3 vs google reCaptcha Enterprise

Tags: google-cloud-platform, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

does anyone know how many API calls can i make for the google reCaptcha v3.

And

What are the main difference in reCaptcha v3 and reCaptcha Enterprise.

Comment: You can see a full version comparison [here](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/compare-versions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Limits of reCAPTCHA:
1000 calls per second or 1000000 calls per month ([Link1](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/), [Linl2](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#are-there-any-qps-or-daily-limits-on-my-use-of-recaptcha))

You can find a comparison of features between reCAPTCHA versions in this link:
https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/integrate-account-verification

The main advantage of reCaptcha enterprise [in my opinion] is Multi-factor authentication (MFA) support.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that on top of the call limit, the implementation of enterprise is different then V3.  For V3, we usually use a REST API to authenticate and verify the reCaptcha.  When using enterprise, we usually use a google cloud library for the language you're currently using.